# iOS Application Settings Bundle

Tags: ios, settings, conditional-statements, bundle

Using Apple's Settings bundle in a project, is it possible to expose certain settings to the user only if another setting condition is met?

E.g I have a toggle switch, and if the user toggles the selection to False in the Settings application, I want to show a text box that they can fill in.  If the toggle is true, I want to hide the text box.

Any help or pointers to documentation that explain this would be great.

Answer (score 5):

You can find step by step instructions here: [Adding a settings bundle to an iPhone App](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/5/18/adding-a-settings-bundle-to-an-iphone-app.html).

---

Edit:
I did my research and I think you cannot do this in an App Store approved app, because to reach this thing you have to change the settings.bundle file inside the application's bundle, which is not allowed in App Store approved apps.

Comment: I know how to create a Settings bundle, and get access to it in my app. My question is more directed at if I cab conditionally show some Settings based on the value of other Settings. See the example in the initial question...