# How do I add a plist file to Setting.bundle programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, settings.bundle

I am trying to add a plist file to the Settings.bundle in my iOS project programmatically.  How would I go about doing this?

I used [Apple's API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/CreatePropListProgram/CreatePropListProgram.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH5-SW1) to find where to put a created plist file to see if the Settings.bundle would check there for a plist file but it doesn't recognize it and the child pane goes to a blank screen instead of showing the settings.

The reason for this is based on the user logging in to my app I want to have different settings show in the Settings App

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. Settings.bundle is supposed to be created at compile time, and is fixed (as well as *signed* as part of the application build process.)

See [the Settings.bundle documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) which explicitly states (emphasis added):

> A Settings bundle has the name Settings.bundle and **resides in the top-level directory of your app’s bundle**.

The emphasized part is what tells me you can't put the bundle anywhere else. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4901767/39974) confirms what I just said.

Conditionally displayed settings are [also not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901726/ios-application-settings-bundle).

Comment: Has this been submitted to Apple as an enhancement? Apple could add the ability to let us hide settings using the same identifier we use to retrieve the value or access to the setting parameters the same way.

Comment: @zurbergram I don't know. I get the feeling that they intentionally made Settings bundles underpowered; why, I have no idea. I understand not letting us write a plugin for the Settings app, but as it stands now, they should probably just deprecate it altogether. Almost everyone that needs it just implements a preferences screen in-app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.  The OS handles that independently, and you aren't allowed to run any code to affect it.

Instead, you are going to want to offer a settings screen within your app that allows full control over the presentation and function.