# Dynamically Changing the Values of Root.plist File in Settings.bundle

Tags: ios

Is there anyway to change the values of some tags in the Root.plist file contained inside the Settings.bundle.

Or

Is there anyway I can use two different Root.plist file for the Settings.bundle.

In my scenario the settings of the app changes for different environments? By settings I mean Click on "Settings" of iPhone and then click on the "App" and you can see settings if you have any?

UPDATE: How do I change the values of item[0], item[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AbrB.png), item[2] dynamically in the code. [image]

Comment: Why negative?? This is a very legitimate question!!

Comment: Do you want to change which settings are available, or do you want to change the values of those settings? (For example, if I have a setting "Foo," do you want to show "Foo" sometimes but not others? Or do you just want to set "Foo" to one value sometimes and another value other times, but leave it called "Foo" no matter what?)

Comment: I want to change the value of those settings.

Comment: Maybe you can find some ideas here:

https://www.logisticinfotech.com/blog/setting-bundle-ios-application/

I've dynamically connected the App version number to the Title in the settings

Answer (score 1):

You can update values stored in the Settings.bundle via NSUserDefaults. Check out more in Apple's [Preferences and Settings Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html)

Comment: From what I can tell in your update and from your comments above, this answer still stands.

Comment: @Tim: I have similar problem. from the above question, how can i get the title "Environment" of the identifier "environment_preference". i need to localize the title dynamically.

Comment: @iPhoneGuy: you should ask a separate question for a fuller answer, but the short version is that you should localize your settings bundle and provide a `.strings` file for each locale that you want "Environment" to appear differently in. See [this top Google result](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/12/17/localizing-iphone-app-settings-strings.html) for a walkthrough, or [Apple's info about settings bundles](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) for technical details.

Comment: @Tim: i have asked the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296249/set-title-string-to-settings-bundle-ios

Answer (score 0):

Touch your Settings.bundle FOLDER, and make sure your Run script is running BEFORE Copy Bundle Resources, e.g.

```
touch "$SRCROOT/Settings.bundle"
```

Seems like it's an Xcode bug - because the Root.plist file gets modified just fine, but Xcode is apparently looking only at the Folder.

Answer (score -1):

You can't edit the content of the `Root.plist` since the `Settings.bundle` is inside the App Bundle wich is readonly.

You could however define your own mapping for values you read from NSUserDefaults to your dynamic values.

Comment: Similar question, similar answer. 
Downvoted by mistake, sorry.
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/4901767/9480608]