# Set Title String to Settings Bundle iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, xcode5, settings.bundle

I need to localize my setting screen text dynamically based on the iphone setting language/user preferred language. In my scenario, localized text are fetching from the server. I am storing text in database and showing it on the screen. Setting screen should be localized based on the user preferred language/device language. I tried to access the title string of an Item in Root.plist. But it returns value but i need title. How can i access/change the title of the item.

for eg:

```
{
        DefaultValue = 1;
        Key = "enabled_preference";
        Title = "Keep me logged in";
        Type = PSToggleSwitchSpecifier;
    }

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"enabled_preference"];
```

which return the value as 1 but i need the title "Keep me logged in" which needs to be changed.

i need a "Title" to be localized (ie) instead of using .lproj file, i have set of localized strings in a dictionary. i need to the set the title with value from dictionary.

How can i accomplish this.

Thanks

Comment: i am not sure i understood the question, but if you want to set a value for a key, try this [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"the object" forKey:@"enabled_preference" ];!! if you are not looking for this, kindly elaborate a little

Comment: @Harsh: i edited my question. i need to get the "Title" string (i.e) Keep me logged in. i need to change this to different language string which i have it in dictionary.

Comment: try this [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:NSLocalizedString(@"title", @"Comments") forKey:@"title" ];  does this solve your problem?

Comment: no. it is not working. setObject:forKey (forKey always match against the "Key" in dictionary)

Comment: so actually you want to get all the key's first, localize them and then the values, localize them aswell?

Comment: Yes. i am doing some tweak similar to that. i tried to fetch using NSUserDefault. But it seems to be not helpful. now i am looping all values in dictionary and changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way where you can get all the values and keys.

This might help you, get all the keys and traverse everyone to get the key you are looking for

all values:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allValues]);
```

all keys:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys]);
```

all keys and values:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
```

using for:

```
NSArray *keys = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys];

for(NSString* key in keys){
// your code here
NSLog(@"value: %@ forKey: %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:key],key);
}
```